# How to hide and display html input text and paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display paragraph and input text based on the drop down value.
I wrote below code but it is not working perfectly for me.
Input text never displaying or hiding properly.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function nameChange(){
        var a = document.getElementById("shape").value;
        if(a=="Circle"){
            document.getElementById("geometry").innerHTML = "Please provide Radius of Circle: ";
            document.getElementById("geometry1").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("Input1").style.visibility = "visible";
        }else if(a=="Triangle"){
            document.getElementById("geometry").innerHTML = "Please provide Dimension of Triangle: ";
            document.getElementById("geometry1").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("Input1").style.visibility = "visible";
        }else if(a=="Square"){
            document.getElementById("geometry").innerHTML = "Please provide Dimension of Square: ";
            document.getElementById("geometry1").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("Input1").style.visibility = "visible";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("geometry").innerHTML = "Please provide Length of Rectangle: ";
            document.getElementById("geometry1").innerHTML = "Please provide Breath of Rectangle: ";
            document.getElementById("Input1").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("Input2").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }

</script>               
<select id="shape" onChange="nameChange()">
  <option value="Triangle">Triangle</option>
  <option value="Rectangle">Rectangle</option>
  <option value="Circle">Circle</option>
  <option value="Square">Square</option>
</select>
<p id="geometry" /p>
    <input id="Input1" type="text" stype="display:none">

 <p id="geometry1" /p> 
    <input id="Input2" type="text" stype="display:none">

</html>
```

Comment: You have not closed your `p` tags properly. `<p id="geometry" /p>` should be either `<p id="geometry" />` or `<p id="geometry"></p>`

Comment: also, it's "style", not "stype"... and "style" should be on your <p>

Comment: And this seems like the perfect example of where a _switch_ would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, it should work. There were multiple typos & paragraph tag was not properly closed.

JS Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function nameChange(){
        var a = document.getElementById("shape").value;
        if(a=="Circle"){
            document.getElementById("geometry").innerHTML = "Please provide Radius of Circle: ";
            document.getElementById("geometry1").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("Input1").style.display = "block";
        }else if(a=="Triangle"){
            document.getElementById("geometry").innerHTML = "Please provide Dimension of Triangle: ";
            document.getElementById("geometry1").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("Input1").style.display = "block";
        }else if(a=="Square"){
            document.getElementById("geometry").innerHTML = "Please provide Dimension of Square: ";
            document.getElementById("geometry1").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("Input1").style.display = "block";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("geometry").innerHTML = "Please provide Length of Rectangle: ";
            document.getElementById("geometry1").innerHTML = "Please provide Breath of Rectangle: ";
            document.getElementById("Input1").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("Input2").style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
```

HTML Code

```
<select id="shape" onChange="nameChange()">
    <option value="Triangle">Triangle</option>
    <option value="Rectangle">Rectangle</option>
    <option value="Circle">Circle</option>
    <option value="Square">Square</option>
</select>
<p id="geometry"></p>
<input id="Input1" type="text" style="display:none">
<p id="geometry1"></p> 
<input id="Input2" type="text" style="display:none">
```